# Coding player names for tic tac toe in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe game in VB.net for a school project. The project requires the game to be two player and it needs to make sure that both players get to enter their names before going into the game but I'm just confused on how to do this part and how to make the players input their names and go into the game afterwards.

Comment: As you should be doing for any programming problem, forget it's a programming problem. Assume that you have to do it manually. What are the steps you would perform? Break the steps down until they are as small as they can be and that is your algorithm. Test it manually to make sure it works. Now, all you have to do is write code to implement that algorithm. Each step is so basic that writing code to do it is easy, so writing all the code is easy. Basically, don't think about writing code until you know what it has to do.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a school assignement where the goal is learning, I'll try to limit my answer a bit, as to not show the full solution.

Generally, independent of what language you use, user input is obtained in two ways:

- If the program does not spawn a graphical interface, usually you want to ask for the input on the command line
- Alternatively, you can spawn a text-box or some graphical element that lets you type / select your input.

A good way to google for something like this is "visual basic user input"

One of the most common results is InputBox, which is probably what I would start with.